# how to get rid of network error(TCP_ERROR) in BIRT?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, networking, tcp, birt

I am new to [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) and would like to see if it meets our reporting needs. I am trying to use BIRT from my *Windows 7* laptop to create a report which accesses a `MySQL` database. I am using the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` driver and connecting to the mysql database using the URL: `jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/databasename` and the test connection is successful and event previewing the data from the Data Set is successful but when I try and run the report I get the error

> Network Error (tcp_error)  A communication error occurred: "Operation
>   timed out" 
>   The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Has anyone seen this before and if so, how do I overcome this?

Comment: this type error occurs when your proxy settings are not properly set.
also if your proxy settings are okey then you need to verify the port number.
So contact to network team and ask for proper proxy.
It will definitely solve your problem.
I hope you have got the answer thank you

Comment: Another solution
Open the Configuration Panel, Network connections. Select the network connection that's giving you troubles. Right click on it, select properties. Remove QOS service. Check the TCP/IP settings: if they're setup by DHCP, leave things as they are. If not, write down all information in that screen and change it to DHCP. Reboot and you should be on your way.

Comment: Are you trying to answer your own question in comments?

Comment: I found some solution
I was unable to answer the question so i did it in comment

Comment: You should be able to post your own answer and accept it now. You had to wait 48 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution Open the Configuration Panel, Network connections. Select the network connection that's giving you troubles. Right click on it, select properties. Remove QOS service. Check the TCP/IP settings: if they're setup by DHCP, leave things as they are. If not, write down all information in that screen and change it to DHCP. Reboot and you should be on your way