# IIS Network Error (tcp_error)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, tcp

I have a problem when using IIS. I deployed a web project at a server, then run "local" at this server, its ok. But when I connect from another computer, I get this message

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
>   The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to
>   try again at a later time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

Please help me fix this error. Sorry my English is not good. Thank you.

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650239/how-to-get-rid-of-network-errortcp-error-in-birt

Comment: @IrishChieftain: I follow your link but still get the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, click on start -> run -> iisreset. And test to see if that fixes it.

Secondly, if there are other sites on the same IIS try giving different ports.

Alternatively, if you are using ip address, try computer name. As a quick fix this may work.

Edit: From your comment the computer hosting the application is 172.29.3.36. Try it's name in the url i.e. `http://myComputerName:8080/index.aspx`. If you're running windows 7 or similar you can type 'computer name' into the start menu and select 'See the name of this computer'. Or start menu->computer (right click and select 'properties' on computer).

Also, check the iis logs for more clues on the error: c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles. C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Comment: First up : I run iireset but no thing change. Secondly : I have one site in IIS. I dont know about "try computer name" ? My client use this link to connect to server : http://172.29.3.36:8080/Index.aspx

Comment: I've updated my comment for using the computer name instead of ip address in the url.

Comment: thank you. Follow your suggest and I find the reason. Cause the port of Server isnt correct. Thank you.