# Solution for Network Error (tcp_error)

Tags: tcp

I get the following error on one of my page:

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

I found a few answer about this questions here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/q/18650239/1478789
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944331/iis-network-error-tcp-error
http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/unable-to-access-one-particular-website-from-any-browser-on-my-pc
```

As a web admin is there anything that can be done to prevent this ? Maybe change apache configuration? Is it correct for me to think that this error occurs from client side?

Comment: tail your apache access and error logs when this happens.

Comment: recreate windows profile du user

Comment: any solution @Jeremy?