# Site crashes when user repeatedly tries to upload invalid file type

Tags: php, http, tcp

I'm trying to understand an error...

I have a web app that allows users to upload CSVs. If the file type is not a CSV, nothing happens and the page simply displays "Invalid File Type."

If the user tries uploading an invalid file type and repeatedly clicks on the button that triggers the PHP file that handles the upload, the PHP file eventually becomes unresponsive and the site crashes with the following error:

```
"tcp_error: The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time"
```

I'm thinking this has to do with the fact that it's a persistent HTTP connection and that it's being overwhelmed by requests?

I'm wondering the precise source of this and the best fix to avoid a crash if the user repeatedly tries to upload an invalid file type.

HTML Excerpt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function stopUpload(success){
              console.log(success);
              var csv1 = success['csv1'];
              var csv2 = success['csv2'];
              var csv3 = success['csv3'];
              var csv4 = success['csv4'];
              var csvError = success['error'];
              var id = success['id'];
              $('.js-wf-error').text(csvError);
              if (!csvError) {
                runWF(id, csv1, csv2, csv3, csv4);
              }
        }
</script>

<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid

<form id="wf-form" class="js-wf-form" method="post" action="wf/csv-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
    <input type="file" name="csv1" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv2" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv3" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv4" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
  <a  href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;" type="submit"class="button redButton largeButton run-wf-button">Run Walking Farm</a>
</form>
```

csv-upload.php

```
(...upload handling...)
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.top.window.stopUpload(<?php print json_encode($returnData); ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just disable the button until a response is returned?

Comment: Yeah was thinking that may work, I'll give it a shot. I want to understand the exact cause of the problem though. When it crashed, I did 5-10 requests in rapid succession that worked fine and only after that when I issued some more requests did it crash, so it's not clear if the problem is that the new request is being issued before the last one returns or whether it's due to the cumulative number of requests...

Comment: You will need to check your server logs to see whats going on, it doesn't appear to be a normal PHP error

Comment: Maybe caused by QOS similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650239/how-to-get-rid-of-network-errortcp-error-in-birt

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the server is still busy with the other requests. Sending a new upload request, does not cancel the upload(s) in progress! It handles some of them in parallel, depending also on how many threads are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  giving  it  a  shot.It  may  work  but  not  guaranteed:
When uploading files via  html  form it can take several seconds before the form is successfully uploaded and the response page(PHP) shown. People can get impatient and click the Upload button several times which can result in duplicate form submissions or  uploads. Usually it's  really a problem &  you might want to prevent this from happening.
You  can  use  javascript  to  handle  it  like  this:
The first step is to give your submit button a unique id, for example id="myButton":

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myButton" />
```

The second (and last) step is to give two Javascript commands to the  tag. The first one will tell the browser to disable the submit button after the form has been submitted and the second one will change the button text to give the user some idea about what's happening. This is the code to add to your form tag:

```
onsubmit="document.getElementById('myButton').disabled=true;

document.getElementById('myButton').value='Uploading to  server, please wait...';"
```

Your form tag would then look something like:

```
<form action="wf/cs-vupload.php" method="post"
onsubmit="document.getElementById('myButton').disabled=true;
document.getElementById('myButton').value='Uploading to  server,please wait...';"

>
```

That's it. This trick should work in most modern browsers (IE 5+, FireFox, Opera, ...).

There  is  one  more  method  of  using  cookies  and  these  quick  fixes  will  prevent  multiple  form  submissions.Try  this  link  :http://myphpform.com/prevent-multiple-form-submissions.php

Did,  I  missed  something.glad  to  know  if  it  is  true.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like the browser is timing out because your server is busy with all the other (upload) requests.

There is a jQuery method called `one()` that executes an event **only once**, which should solve this problem well.

For example:

```
<form id="wf-form" class="js-wf-form" method="post" action="wf/csv-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
    <input type="file" name="csv1" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv2" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv3" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
    <input type="file" name="csv4" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
  <a  href="#" id="submit_link" type="submit"class="button redButton largeButton run-wf-button">Run Walking Farm</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit_link").one( "click", function() {
        $("#wf-form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

For completeness sake: If it was not a link but a button, you could simply disable the submit button in the onClick event (right after the `submit()`), to disallow submitting the files more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) Javascript class for ajax upload files and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for form class.

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>

    <form id="wf-form" class="js-wf-form" method="post" action="wf/csv-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
        <input type="file" name="csv1" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
        <input type="file" name="csv2" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
        <input type="file" name="csv3" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
        <input type="file" name="csv4" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all csv-upload" />
<input type="hidden" value="1000000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
      <a  href="#" onclick="fcsvUpload(); return false;" type="submit"class="button redButton largeButton run-wf-button">Run Walking Farm</a>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

         function fcsvUpload(){
            var oData = new FormData(document.getElementById("wf-form"));
            var result = true;



            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("POST", "wf/csv-upload.php", false);

            oReq.send(oData);

            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                return result;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

You have error in html line with iframe. iframe tag isnt closed. Maybe because it doesnt work. Look:

```
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid
```